# Change date format in C# when reading from database and setting to label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, string, date

I am trying to read a `date` field from database and set it to a label field. Im using the following code,

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select BirthDate from Student where Name=@name", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Mano");

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

lblName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Date"].ToString();
```

But this displays the data value in label in the format `02-05-1991 00:00:00` but I want to display it in format `dd-mm-yyyy` as `05-02-1991`. So I tried the following code:

```
lblName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["BirthDate"].ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

But it shows this error:

> No overload for method ToString takes 1 argument

How can I change the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `BirthDate` represents a valid `DateTime`, convert it before calling `ToString()`.

```
lblName.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["BirthDate"]).ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

You're currently calling the `ToString()` method on the object class, not the `DateTime` class, so there's no overload that allows for a date formatter.

Comment: Its working im using `date` format in SQL table..with value `05-02-1991` but in C# when i give format as `dd-mm-yyyy` it displays in label as `02-05-1991` does this means SQL stores `date` format as `mm-dd-yyyy` ??

Comment: No, it means the given format string is wrong, it should be `dd-MM-yyyy` as `mm` in DateTime formats mean **minutes** not months.

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat your date value as a DateTime and then call the overload of ToString from the DateTime structure that has the required formatting option.

Actually you are converting the row value to a string and a string knows nothing about how to format a date.

```
DateTime t = dt.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("Date");
lblName.Text = t.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Also pay attention to the correct format for the Months part. It is an uppercase `M`. The lowercase `m` is for minutes.