# C# changing date format from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql

I'm relatively new to C#, SQL Server, and Stackoverflow.

I want the format of my date to stay the same from SQL Server to my C# code.
I have a screenshot of the SQL Server table:

[image: a screenshot of the sql table].

I just want the format to stay the same. I want the format to stay `yyyy-mm-dd` instead when I retrieve the data the format is `dd/mm/yyyy 0:00:00`.

I then use the following code to retrieve the data from the server:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList(); 
DataTable d = new DataTable();         
string sql = "SELECT * FROM myServer";

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
MySqlDataAdapter myA = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

myA.Fill(d);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

foreach (DataRow row in d.Rows)
{
    FitnessManager f = new FitnessManager();
    f.testDate = row["testDate"].ToString();
    f.tDate = row["tDate"].ToString();
    f.dtDate = row["dtDate"].ToString(); 
    a.Add(f);
}

return a;
```

I would expect the results in the `ArrayList` to be `2020-10-13`, instead I'm getting `10/11/2020 0:00:00`.

I do not know why this happens for how to fix this.

Comment: Both a `DATE` in SQL and a `DateTime` in .NET are binary objects. What you see in both cases is *two different representations* of the same (or maybe translated, but similar) binary data. In both systems there are many options to control the translation from binary data to strings.

Comment: Your posted code snippet is marked *JavaScript*, not *C#*. The screenshot of the table is not useful - please specify which SQL datatype your datetime is in SQL (there are several, such as `datetime`, `smalldatetime`, etc). Please improve this post so we can help you.

Comment: Also, you should really not use `ArrayList`

Comment: Why do you use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`? It useless in your code.

Comment: So the datatypes in the sql table are DATE datatypes. I was using ArrayList, because it is what I'm using in my larger project. cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() was just a copy and paste from another part of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
  f.tDate = row["tDate"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

The ToString() function accepts a format string, so you can pretty much convert it to whatever format you want.

More information here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

I found a previous post that helped me out a lot.

[Change date format in C# when reading from database and setting to label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933065/change-date-format-in-c-sharp-when-reading-from-database-and-setting-to-label)
I needed to specify that the data being formatted was datatime rather than ToString() being called as an object.

Thanks E.J for putting me on the right track.